# Issue while returning the errors list

Tags: django

**Below is code in views.py file.**

```
class login(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    def post(self, request):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            return HttpResponse("ok")
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
            return HttpResponse(form)
```

**Below code is in template file.**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'authapp:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Login
    </button>
</form>
```

**below code is in forms.py file**

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True),
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
```

**Issue Details**

When i submit the form with both username and password empty, it returns just a textfield of password.

I was expecting a list of errors for required username and password. As both are required in forms file.

Can you please suggest something?

Comment: you didn't render your LoginForm to your template at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your views.py so it actually return the forms to the template:

```
class login(View):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            # some validation stuffs
            return HttpResponse("ok")
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Your forms.py so it actually use to render:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="username", max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="password", max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

And your template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'authapp:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.username }}
    {% if form.username.errors %}
       {% for error in form.username.errors %}
          {{ error }}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form.password }}
    {% if form.password.errors %}
       {% for error in form.password.errors %}
           {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Login
    </button>
</form>
```

I think you should finish reading the [form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) before you doing this since last question you didn't know that you have to add forms.py in your project

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the debug true in settings.py file

```
DEBUG = True
```